# Is there a terminology to describe a user (in computer science) who doesn't need to think to do its job?

Tags: terminology, programming

To be more specific, an example:

The customer relationship department of a company has 100 people to work on customer requests. This company has a system in which almost everything is automated for the user, and their only job is to answer simple "questions" on the screen, like if the customer has sent a specific document or not (a "yes or no" question).

The system user doesn't really need to think or have any critical thoughts about the process.

In portuguese we call this kind of "dumb" user a "button masher". I searched this term on Google, but all I got was results about simple games which require little effort from the user. But I wonder if this terminology can be applied to a non-gaming context as well, to describe the user.

Comment: A person who interacts with customers on the phone, but who interacts with an automated system to address the customer’s needs, is essentially an **emotional worker**, since their value to the business comes from their effect on the customer’s state of mind after the interaction.

Comment: If there is no personal interaction with the customer, you can refer to them as a **clerk**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing an "**unskilled** operator".  See this description of [Unskilled Labour](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/unskilled-labor.asp) for details.

Any other terms I can think of are either specific to manual work, or are insults.

Answer (score 1):

The United States Department of Labor has defined an occupation named [data entry keyer](https://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes439021.htm)

> 43-9021 Data Entry Keyers
>
> Operate data entry device, such as keyboard or photo composing perforator. Duties may include verifying data and preparing materials for printing. Excludes "Word Processors and Typists" (43-9022).